# Error while finding lines starting with H or I using Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to learn Spark and Scala. I am working on a scenario to identify the lines that start with H or I. Below is my code

```
def startWithHorI(s:String):String=
{
 if(s.startsWith("I")
 return s
 if(s.startsWith("H")
 return s
}

val fileRDD=sc.textFile("wordcountsample.txt")
val checkRDD=fileRDD.map(startWithHorI)
checkRDD.collect
```

It is throwing an error while creating the function Found:Unit Required:Boolean.

From research I understood that it is not able to recognize the return as Unit means void. Could someone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your def, we will start there:
It is throwing the error because according to the code posted, your syntax is incomplete and the def is defined improperly:

```
def startWithHorI(s:String): String=
{
 if(s.startsWith("I")) // missing extra paren char in original post
 s // do not need return statement
 if(s.startsWith("H")) // missing extra paren char in original post
 s // do not need return statement
}
```

This will still return an error because we are expecting a `String` when the compiler sees that it's returning an `Any`. We cannot do this if we do not have an else case (what will be returned when s does not start with H or I?) - the compiler will see this as an `Any` return type. The correction for this would be to have an else condition that ultimately returns a `String`.

```
def startWithHorI(s: String): String = {
 if(s.startsWith("I")) s else "no I" 
 if(s.startsWith("H")) s else "no H"
}
```

If you don't want to return anything, then an `Option` is worth looking at for a return type.

Finally we can achieve what you are doing via filter - no need to map with a def:

```
val fileRDD = sc.textFile("wordcountsample.txt")
val checkRDD = fileRDD.filter(s => s.startsWith("H") || s.startsWith("I"))
checkRDD.collect
```

Answer (score 0):

While passing any function to `rdd.map(fn)` make sure that `fn` covers all possible scenarios.

If you want to completely avoid strings which does not start with either `H` or `I` then use flatMap and return Option[String] from your function.
Example:

```
def startWithHorI(s:String): Option[String]=
{
    if(s.startsWith("I") || s.startsWith("H")) Some(s)
    else None
}
```

Then,

```
sc.textFile("wordcountsample.txt").flatMap(startWithHorI)
```

This will remove all rows not starting with H or I.

In general, to minimize run-time errors try to create `total functions` which handles all possible values of the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below would work for you?

```
val fileRDD=sc.textFile("wordcountsample.txt")
fileRDD.collect
Array[String] = Array("Hello ", Hello World, Instragram, Good Morning)


val filterRDD=fileRDD.filter( x=> (x(0) == 'H'||x(0) == 'I'))
filterRDD.collect()
Array[String] = Array("Hello ", Hello World, Instragram)
```